# Python: How to show rows of data from dataframe then prompt the user again for the next batch of rows

Tags: python, dataframe, input, printing

I would like to know how to write a loop that prompts the user each time a row of data is displayed from the dataframe. If the user answers 'yes', the function will display the row of data and re-prompts the user until there is no more rows. If the user answers 'no', the loop should break.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(10,3))
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    ans = input("Would you like to print a row? ")
    if  ans == 'yes':
        print("Row : {!r}".format(row.tolist()))
    elif ans == 'no':
        break
    else:
        print("Omit row # {}".format(ind))
```